# React Native Gifted Chat + Firestore - messages render one-by-one instead of simultaneously

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-gifted-chat

Expected behavior: all messages in a chat render seamlessly at the same time

Observed behavior: upon mounting component or sending a new message, the messages disappear and then re-render one-by-one in chronological order. Here is a gif of the current behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEO40.jpg

I'm fairly certain this is to do with how I'm handling the interaction between firestore and component state but I'm unsure about how to proceed.

```
export default class Chat extends React.Component {

state = {
  messages: [],
  currentUser: null,
  chatID: '',
  courseTitle: ''
};

componentDidMount(){
    // get user info from firestore
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser._user
    firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).get().then(doc => {
        data = doc.data()
        this.setState({currentUser: {
            name: data.name,
            email: data.email,
            avatar: data.avatar,
            _id: doc.id,
        }})
    })

    // make a call to firestore to retrieve the chat data
    let chatID = this.props.navigation.state.params.id
    this.setState({chatID: chatID})
    firestore().collection("chats").doc(chatID).onSnapshot((doc) => {
        this.setState({ messages: [], courseTitle: doc.data().courseTitle })
        let newArray = []
        doc.data().messages.map(item => {
            firestore().collection("messages").doc(item).onSnapshot((doc) => {
                let message = doc.data()
                message['_id'] = doc.id
                newArray.push(message)
                this.setState(previousState => ({
                    messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, message)
                }))
            })
        })
    })
}

 get user() {
    currentUser = this.state.currentUser
    return {
        name: currentUser.name,
        email: currentUser.email,
        avatar: currentUser.avatar.uri,
        _id: currentUser._id
    };
}

get timestamp() {
    return firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
}

onSend(messages = []) {
    for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        const { text, user } = messages[i];
        const message = {
            text,
            user,
            timestamp: this.timestamp,
        };

       firestore().collection("messages").add(message).then((doc) => {
            const id = doc.id
            firestore().collection("chats").doc(this.state.chatID).update({
                messages: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(id)
            })
       })
    }
}

goBack = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
}

render() {
  return (
    <>
    {this.state.currentUser ?
        <>
        <BackHeader title={this.state.courseTitle} command={this.goBack} titleSize={12} />
        <GiftedChat
        showUserAvatar={true}
        renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
        user={this.user}
        />
        </>
    : null }
    </>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: hi are you still looking for solution?

Comment: Please tell me you found a solution! would help me a ton!

Comment: @HarshitMadhav I just asked a question that is related if you know the solution! just check my profile :)

Comment: @kalculated I attained it using apis not firestore and also I am not able to find the question that you are referring to in your profile

Comment: I was able to solve the issue! @HarshitMadhav